# Google PHP API with Fusion Tables - Trying to UPDATE a cell value using PHP of my own table. 500 Server Error

Tags: google-api, google-fusion-tables, google-api-client

I have been looking everywhere for some documentation on using the Google PHP APIs and this is as close as I have managed to get. In the "sql" function there is a line within the Google API code which is crucial "__call('sql'....)" - but this causes a 500 Server Error. Can anyone give me a hand in where I might be going wrong? I originally was going to call the UPDATE function via Javascript which returns "401 unauthorized" - but also have big problems trying to get oauth working for a Service Account. Basically I am trying to allow a website CMS user to update a value in a column on a specific ROWID of my own table and do not need access to their personal data/tables etc.

Thanks in advance!

```
require_once 'google-api-php-client-read-only/src/Google_Client.php';
require_once 'google-api-php-client-read-only/src/contrib/Google_FusiontablesService.php';
ini_set("DISPLAY_ERRORS",1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

// Set your client id, service account name, and the path to your private key.
// For more information about obtaining these keys, visit:
// https://developers.google.com/console/help/#service_accounts
$CLIENT_ID = '278066061539-e80g63vcqkaj28frfn6g32vbll38onsn.apps.googleusercontent.com';
$SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME = '278066061539-e80g63vcqkaj28frfn6g32vbll38onsn@developer.gserviceaccount.com';

// Make sure you keep your key.p12 file in a secure location, and isn't
// readable by others.
$KEY_FILE = 'scriptonly/2655a395f392632a75bcdc139c47aa70d20d71f1-privatekey.p12';

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("SIE Stop Smoking Services");

// Set your cached access token. Remember to replace $_SESSION with a
// real database or memcached.
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
 $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
}

// Load the key in PKCS 12 format (you need to download this from the
// Google API Console when the service account was created.
$key = file_get_contents($KEY_FILE);
$client->setAssertionCredentials(new Google_AssertionCredentials(
    $SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME,
    array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fusiontables'),
    $key)
);

$client->setClientId($CLIENT_ID);

$client->getAccessToken();
$service = new Google_FusiontablesService($client);

$service->query->sql("UPDATE 1z3anmPv-gPfB-MQGy_qCGWabBJVCk1BCoda0qXs SET SSS_Quality='1' WHERE ROWID='4'");
```

Answer (score 2):

I just updated my google-api-php-client to the latest revision (r476) and created an [UPDATE example](https://github.com/odi86/GFTPrototype/blob/master/examples/php/UpdateTable.php), which [works for me](http://gft.rdmr.ch/examples/php/UpdateTable.php). I can't spot an obvious mistake in your code.

Are you sure, that the Service Account has permissions to update the table? Please check that `278066061539-e80g63vcqkaj28frfn6g32vbll38onsn@developer.gserviceaccount.com` has the "Can edit" permission.

Comment: I found that I also needed to share the table with the service account email address, which I found odd since I though the whole API thing would have provided access to all tables I own.

Comment: That's what I meant with the update permission. In general you are right, but the Service Account really is a different account than your own. It belongs rather to your application ;) Therefore you have more control over what your application can and can't do.